# Yodlee - When to use MFA?

Tags: authentication, yodlee

I am using Yodlee to get users bank account information. I've already implemented a sample account which uses `FieldInfoSingle` authentication, but I know that Bank of America uses MFA with security questions.

When I call `getSiteLoginForm` API, it returns `username` and `password`. When I call `getSiteInfo` API, it returns `mfaType.typeName: SECURITY_QUESTION`.

1. Do I have to call `addSiteAccount1` with MFA fields?
2. How do I get the user's questions to send its answers?

I've readed Yodlee documentation and it refers to MFA only when user attempts to refresh the account. Sorry, but I am confused about "refresh" concept.

I hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not pass MFA fields in addSiteAccount1 API. Instead call the addSiteAccount1 API with the userName and password and then once process starts then you will have to call another API called [getMFAResponseForSite](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getMFAResponseForSite) API which will return you the questions that are asked at the bank site and then you need to pass in the answer though [putMFARequestForSite](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/putMFARequestForSite)

You should also follow this [API flow](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow/Add_Site_Account) and it will help you in making the right API calls in order to link your account.